# Let $w$ be a positive continuous function for which $\int_0^1 w(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^2w(x)dx = 1$. Prove that $\int_0^1 xw(x)dx < 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $w$ be a positive continuous function for which $$\int_0^1 w(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^2w(x)dx = 1.$$ Prove that $\int_0^1 xw(x)dx < 1$.

I was thinking of using the Reisz Representation Theorem for this but my intuitive understanding of it is lacking. I would love some guidance on this proof, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu (E)=\int_E w(x)dx$. Then $\mu$ is a  probability measure and $\int x^{2}d\mu(x)=1$. Hence $\int xd\mu (x)\leq \sqrt {\int x^{2} d\mu (x)}=1$. Equality can hold only when the integrand is a constant a.e. $[\mu]$ which is obviously false. Hence $\int xd\mu (x) <1$.

Alternatively $\int xw(x)dx=\int (x\sqrt {w(x)})(\sqrt {w(x)}  dx \leq \sqrt {\int x^{2}w(x)dx} \sqrt {\int w(x)dx}=1$ and equality is ruled out as above.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't been exposed to probability measures so I don't know if I should use this approach. Do you know an alternative, linear-algebra-based solution?

Comment: I have added another proof.

Comment: Does this proof hold for the closed interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. The integrals are same whether you have open interval $(0,1)$ or closed interval $[0,1]$. And the  integrals in my proof  are all over this interval.

Comment: You're correct, I realized that just now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you maybe elaborate on why equality gets ruled out in the second proof? It's just not entirely clear to me. When you say "equality is ruled out as above" are you referencing your statement "Equality can only hold when the integrand is a constant"? If so, then I understand.

Comment: In Cauchy Schwarz inequality: $\int fg \leq \sqrt {\int f^{2}} \sqrt {\int g^{2}}$ quality can occur only when $f=cg$ for some constant $c \geq 0$.  @GrayLiterature